# Max Tasks that can be completed in given time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I recently came across a this question in a forum:
You are given a straight line starting at 0 to 10^9. You start at zero and there are n tasks you can perform. i th task is located at point i in the line and requires 't' time to be performed. To perform the task you need to reach the point i and spend 't' time at that location.

example: (5,8) lies at 5 so travel distance is 5 and work effort is 8.
Total effort is calculated as travel distance + time required to complete the work.
It takes one sec to travel one unit of path.

Now we are given total T seconds and we need to complete as many tasks as possible and reach back to starting position
Find the max number of tasks that you can finish in time T.

example :

3 16 - 3 tasks and 16 units of total time

2 8 - task 1 at position 2 in line and takes 8 sec to complete

4 5 - task 2 at position 4 in line and takes 5 sec to complete

5 1 - task 3 at position 5 in line and takes 1 sec to complete

​​​​​​​
Output : 2

Explanation :
If we take task 1 at location 2 which requires 8 sec then getting to location 2 takes 2s and completing the task takes 8s leaving us with only 6s which is not enough for completing other task

On the other hand skipping the fist task leaves us enough time to complete the other two tasks.

Going to location and coming back costs 2x5 =10s and performing task at location 4 and 5 cost us 5+1 = 6s. Total time spent will be 10s+6s=16s.

I am new to graphs and DP so I was not sure which approach to use Hamiltonian cycle, Knapsack or Longest Path.
Can someone please help me with the most efficient approach to solve this.

Comment: Maybe there's some way to reinterpret the problem as one of the 3 you listed, but I think the most useful approach is always to look for ways to break the problem you do have into subproblems in such a way that solutions to subproblems can be combined into solutions to larger subproblems. Once you have that, you can solve the problem recursively. You might get a divide & conquer right away, or you might find that the same subproblems are getting solved multiple times, in which case you can add memoisation on top to get a DP algorithm. If not, look for a different subdivision into subproblems.

Comment: Please let me know if I missed anything, it's always difficult to describe such a problem without using its standard notation. Say that you have a set K of tasks that you may or may not perform at a point s_k in time for p_k unit of time. You're looking for the subset I of K which maximizes the value V = 2 * max_K {s_k} + sum_K {p_k} where V <= UB, with UB an arbitrary upper bound. If you set s_i = 0 for all i in I you can certainly reduce you problem to PARTITION. Based on your previous comment, are you looking for an heuristic or for the optimum solution?

Comment: @PhM75 the goal is to maximize the size of subset. And as you mentioned V = 2 * max_K {s_k} + sum_K {p_k} and V<=UB. I'm looking for the optimal solution to solve this problem.

Comment: @Hari, at first see the problem is weakly NP-hard (I might be wrong); do you know what is its exact complexity class and/or its best known complexity?

Comment: @PhM75 yes it seems like a NP-hard problem. I could not find any editorial for this problem so i'm not sure . . but the given range of values for N(no of tasks) was  1<=N<=10^5 . 
So I guess the algorithm should ideally be O(nlogn) or O(n) .
And total time range was 0<=T<=10^8.

Comment: @Hari, sorry I misread the prblem description and the solution below based  on 2 * distance(i) + effort(i) looks to be correct

Answer (score 4):

Let's iterate from the first task to the last, according to distance. As we go, it's clear that after subtracting `2 * distance(i) + effort(i)` for considering the current task as our last, the most tasks we can achieve can be found by greedily accumulating as many earlier tasks as possible into the remaining time, ordering them by increasing effort.

Therefore, an efficient solution could insert the seen element into a data-structure ordered by effort, dynamically updating the best solution so far. (I originally thought of using a [treap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990421/2034787) and binary search but j_random_hacker suggested a much simpler way in the comments below this answer.)

Comment: An ordinary binary max-heap suffices. Keep deleting the highest-effort element until we are at or under the time limit, then, if effort(i) < effort(topOfHeap), delete one more element and insert i.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't follow. Could you please outline a general procedure?

Comment: With tasks in increasing position order, for i from 1 to n, we calculate the optimal number f(i) of tasks that can be completed assuming that we move as far right as pos(i) but no further. (Note we *don't* assume that we actually complete task i.) f(i) is the maximum number of tasks from { 1, ..., i } that will fit into t - 2\*pos(i), which can be found greedily as you said. Invariant: tasks in the max-heap are an optimal solution for the current i, so f(i) is just the size of the max-heap after performing the deletions and possible insertion. The max over all f(i) is a solution.

Comment: (Although computing a single f(i) value could entail multiple deletions from the max-heap, no element is ever deleted more than once, so these deletions can be charged to their insertion steps. The heap size is <= n, so we get O(n log n) time overall.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker thanks, I think I follow it now and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

For each task n create a graph like this

[image]

Join up these graphs for all the tasks.

[image]

Run a travelling salesman algorithm to find the minimum time to do all the tasks ( = visit all the nodes in combined graph )

Remove tasks in an orderly sequence.  This will give you a collection of results for different numbers of tasks performed.  Choose the one that does the most number of tasks that still remains under the time limit.

Since you are maximizing the number of tasks performed, start by removing the longest tasks so that you will be left with lots of short tasks.

Comment: Hi ravenspoint, yes initially I came up with a similar approach but I ran into time limit exceeded error. 
The range of values are as below
1<=N<=10^5
So the algorithm should ideally be O(nlogn) or O(n)

Comment: "Remove tasks in an orderly sequence until the time is within your limit,"

Comment: As I understand from your answer the min time will always be 2*(Pn)+sum(t1+t2..tn) to visit all the nodes.
Because in order to visit all nodes we will need to be at the last node in the graph and the points are unidirectional we will be traversing from start->p1->p2->p3.
Do we need TSP for this or am I missing something. 
Also I will need to remove a subset from this for eg I can remove the following subsets {p1},{p1,p2},{p2},{p2,p3},{p1,p3},{p3} and so on.
Removing in Orderly sequence might not give the correct result.
Please let me know if I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing something.  I have added a ( painfully ) detailed description of how to go about finding the optimum result.